# Mongodb - How to debug aggregation steps?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, debugging, aggregation-framework

How can I debug the MongoDb aggregation steps using native `mongodb` driver for node.js [Node.js Mongodb driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/?)

What I have found by googling is this `npm` package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-aggregation-debugger

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: I debug by writing my query in robomongo.

Comment: Just curious, why are you looking for an alternative?

Comment: @AndrewNessin I was looking for a possibility to halt the aggregation at a specific point and get the intermediate result until this aggregation step. Robo3T is what I'm using now - when building my query I just remove the aggregation steps after the step and look at the temporary result.

Comment: try this https://github.com/entria/debug-mongoose-aggregate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an old post but [Aggregation Pipeline Builder](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/aggregation-pipeline-builder) in [MongoDb Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) works great for debugging. You can build your pipeline with real-time results and errors then export the result to Node.js (Java, Python or C#).